# Using getOoXML in Word Online results in a RichApi.Error: ooxmlIsMalformated error

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I have started Word Online with an empty document (https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx)

I start by inserting an equation, e.g. 1+1 with the equation editor (Insert/Equation)

[Word online document with a simple equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGCfx.png)

I sideloaded a Word Addin in which I can invoke the getOoxml() method. When I invoke this command the following error appears in the console.

word-web-16.00.js:25 Uncaught (in promise) RichApi.Error:
ooxmlIsMalformated
at new n (word-web-16.00.js:25:324636)
at o.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (word-web-16.00.js:25:388802)
at word-web-16.00.js:25:386865

Note that when I delete the equation the command works correctly and it returns the Ooxml with the content of the document.

Does anybody know a way to retrieve the Ooxml including the math equations from a Word document in the Word Online environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue.
It has been put on our backlog<Bug#6764267> for internal track. We will keep track of this issue and let you know if there are any updates.